# Environment variables C

Tags: c, environment-variables

I have to write a programm with a menu. Yhe user can type a number between 0 and 5. 0 ends the programm. 1 lists all env variables, 2 prints one entry, 3 adds an entry, 4 modify entry, 5 remove entry.

When I list all variables the programm crashes with: "Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)"

When I want to print an environment variable, `getenv()` wont find anything, although they exist.

Here is my code. If theres anything else you need to help me, please let me know.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "environment.h"

extern char **environ;

long getMenue(char Menuetitel [50], char Menupunkte[10][100], int Anzahl){

    char* buffer;
    size_t bufsize = 32;
    int i = 0;
    long Auswahl;
    int ok = 0;

    buffer = (char*) malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
    if (buffer == NULL){

        perror("malloc failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("---------------------\n");
    printf("%s\n", Menuetitel);
    printf("---------------------\n");

    while(i < Anzahl){

        printf("%s\n", Menupunkte[i]);
        i++;

    }

    while(ok == 0){
        char* pEnd;
        printf("\nIhre Wahl: ");
        getline(&buffer,&bufsize,stdin);

        Auswahl = strtol(buffer, &pEnd, 10);

        if(Auswahl < 0 || Auswahl > Anzahl){
            printf("Falsche Eingabe. Bitte geben Sie eine Zahl zwischen 0 und 5 ein\n");
            ok = 0;
        }else{
            ok=1;
        }


    }

    return Auswahl;
}
void printList(){
    int i = 0;
    while(*environ){

        puts(*(environ+i));
        i++;
    }

}
void printEntry() {
    char *buffer;
    size_t bufsize = 32;
    size_t characters = 0;
    char * ausgabe;

    buffer = (char *) malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
    if (buffer == NULL) {

        perror("malloc failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (!characters){
        printf("Welchen Eintrag möchten Sie ausgeben?");
        characters = getline(&buffer, &bufsize, stdin);
        ausgabe = getenv(buffer);
        printf("%s\n", buffer);

        if(!characters)
            printf("Bitte geben Sie etwas ein\n");
        else if( ausgabe == NULL)
            printf("Kein Treffer bitte noch einmal versuchen \n");
        else {
            printf("%s = %s\n", buffer, ausgabe);
        }

    }
}
void Add(){
    char *buffer;
    size_t bufsize = 32;
    size_t characters = 0;

    buffer = (char *) malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
    if (buffer == NULL) {

        perror("malloc failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    while(!characters){
        printf("Bitte geben Sie ein, was Sie hinzufügen möchten: ");
        characters = getline(&buffer, &bufsize, stdin);
        if(characters == 0){
            printf("Bitte geben Sie etwas ein\n");
        }else if (putenv(buffer) != 0){
            printf("Putenv() hat nicht funktioniert. Versuchen Sie es erneut\n");
        }
    }
}

void modify(){
    char *buffer;
    size_t bufsize = 32;
    size_t characters = 0;
    char * comp;

    buffer = (char *) malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
    if (buffer == NULL) {

        perror("malloc failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(!characters){

        printf("Welche Variable möchten Sie verändern?");
        characters = getline(&buffer, &bufsize, stdin);
        comp = getenv(buffer);
        if(!characters)
            printf("Bitte geben Sie etwas ein\n");
        else if( comp != NULL){
            setenv(comp, buffer, 1 );
        }else{
            printf("diese Variable gibt es noch nicht\n");
        }
    }
}

void removeEntry(){
    char *buffer;
    size_t bufsize = 32;
    size_t characters = 0;
    char * comp;

    buffer = (char *) malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
    if (buffer == NULL) {

        perror("malloc failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(!characters){

        printf("Welche Variable möchten Sie löschen?\n");
        characters = getline(&buffer, &bufsize, stdin);
        comp = getenv(buffer);
        if(!characters)
            printf("Bitte geben Sie etwas ein\n");
        else if( comp != NULL){
            unsetenv(comp);
        }else{
            printf("diese Variable gibt es noch nicht\n");
        }
    }
}



void environment(){

    long Auswahl =1;

    char Menupunkte[10][100]= {

        "[1]: Print environment list",
        "[2]: Print environment entry",
        "[3]: Add environment entry",
        "[4]: Modify environment entry",
        "[5]: Remove environment entry",
        "[0]: End"
    };


    while (Auswahl != 0){

        Auswahl = getMenue("Environment-List Menu", Menupunkte, 6 );

        switch(Auswahl){

            case 1 : printList(); break;
            case 2 : printEntry(); break;
            case 3 : Add(); break;
            case 4 : modify(); break;
            case 5 : removeEntry(); break;
            case 0 : printf("Programm wird beendet\n"); break;
            default: printf("Falsche Eingabe\n"); break;
        }
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main() {

    environment();

}
```

Comment: Observation: you define `extern char **environ` but you never set it to point to anything.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica Of course not, it's supposed to be initialized by the linker to point to the environment location.

Comment: @Barmar: duh............ :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your `PrintList` routine is the line which reads

```
  while(*environ){
```

In this routine you're not changing the pointer `environ` so `*environ` is a constant - it's the first entry in the array of pointers to which `environ` points. Change this to

```
while(*(environ+i)){
```

Comment: He also needs to increment `i` by `strlen(environ+i)+1`, not by 1.

Comment: `environ[i]` >> `*(environ+i)`. YMMV.

Comment: @user207421: `i` is serving as an index into the array of pointers pointed to by `char **environ` and thus should be incremented by 1. The code to print the environment works properly with the fix I suggested above. [onlinegdb test here](https://onlinegdb.com/HJC92wXoU)